# Installing Ubuntu with LVM/ZFS

Tags: partitioning, lvm, zfs, ubiquity

I don't think I have actually used Ubuntu since I believe Dapper Drake but looking to give it a go now that 20.04 has been released.

I'm having issues with the installation process. I have managed to get it installed using a standard ext4 partition and am pretty impressed so if any of you could give me help with sorting out the partitions in the installation processes I would be grateful.

How can I format and encrypt a specific drive to either ZFS on root or even LVM. These options seem to only be selectable via erase existing drive option. Using a custom partitioning options doesn't seem to allow it.

I have tried to manually set up a LUKS encrypted LVM partition however grub doesn't seem to work (enters command line mode and any command I try to use to boot the system requests the Linux kernel be booted first).

As a bonus question, I believe ZFS relies on a DKMS module, can I manually enroll it so I can still use Secureboot?

Note: I'm duel booting with Windows 10 (bitlocker encrypted) and am looking to use the same EFI partition for grub.

Many thanks,

Comment: Seems like many of your questions will be answered by https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/setup-zfs-storage-pool

Comment: Hello, the issue with ZFS is that the manual partitioning during the installation doesn't give me the option to format/use a ZFS filesystem so setting up a pool manually would still mean I have to reformat it during installation.

Comment: Ah, I understand. I don't boot from ZFS. It adds a layer of complexity at just the wrong time. My servers boot plain ext4 (easier to troubleshoot, easy to reinstall), and mount ZFS pools for the various services they provide. Since I have no experience booting ZFS, I will bow out and let others offer their experience.

Comment: My initial investigation is it doesn't have a 'custom' solution for this that you can configure - there's an experimental 'wipe disk and install on ZFS' but I don't know if that will nuke the entire disk or just the partitions.  I'm unsure if there is a solution to dedicate a single ZFS *partition* in this manner though, so I'm going to spin a VM and investigate the desktop installer a bit.

Comment: @ThomasWard the experimental ZFS option in the installer wipes the whole disk, puts a GPT disk label on it and puts 4 partitions on it, 1) efi 2) swap, 3) boot pool and 4) root pool. The process is not configurable at all at this state, which is a shame because their setup supports out of the box booting from zfs boot volume and unlocking natively encrypted root pool datasets, but the installer wont let you setup the root pool with encrytpion.  I have a home-rolled script to accomplish it, but is not ready for use.  If you look at the ubiquity installer, scripts/zsys-setup is what it does.

Comment: @Casey at the same time creating via "something else" does not work either - so therefore trying to do ZFS on root or LVM on ZFS wont work - OP will have to fall back to standard LVM deployments and ignore ZFS for now at the closest.

Comment: @casey thanks! At least now that I know it's not possible I can happily put my mind to rest. I'll have a look at the ubiquity script.